# Insert static element only once in query archive

Tags: query, archives

I'm looking to insert a foreign div-element only once in a archive query on my page. So that for example:

1. Post1
2. Post2
3. [Static Div]
4. Post4
5. Post5 ...etc

My query is:

```
<?php

$archive_args = array(
post_type => 'post',
'category_name' => 'category',
'posts_per_page'=> -1,
'meta_key' => 'number',
'order' => 'ASC'
);

$archive_query = new WP_Query( $archive_args );?>

<?php while ( $archive_query->have_posts() ) : $archive_query->the_post(); // run the custom loop ?>

<article <?php post_class(); ?>>
The Content
</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Maybe the showposts parameter can be useful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the Index of the post currently being displayed to trigger when your custom content is rendered.

[`current_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods_and_Properties) can be found on [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) from within the loop.

```
<?php while( $archive_query->have_posts() ) :

    $archive_query->the_post(); ?>

    <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
        The Content
    </article>

    <?php if ( $archive_query->current_post === 2 ): ?>

        <div>Custom Content</div>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Upvote for that - I've always used a static counter but this way I guess the custom code could also be injected on a hook into the_post, loop_start or loop_end, letting you do this on any theme.

Comment: Then you could always run your own counter outside the loop. Depends on the particulars, but the OP specifically says 'static element' in this case.